# Poetry clean/remove package from env after removing from toml file

Tags: python, python-poetry

I installed a package with `poetry add X`, and so now it shows up in the toml file and in the venv (mine's at `.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`).

Now to remove that package, I could use `poetry remove X` and I know that would work properly.
But sometimes, it's easier to just go into the toml file and delete the package line there. So that's what I tried by removing the line for X.

I then tried doing `poetry install` but that didn't do anything
When I do `ls .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`, I still see X is installed there.

I also tried `poetry lock` but no change with that either.

So is there some command to take the latest toml file and clean up packages from being installed that are no longer present in the toml?

Comment: `poetry run pip uninstall package-name`

Comment: poetry lock should do it, but try poetry update, or lock --no-update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When ever you manual edit the `pyproject.toml` you have to run `poetry lock --no-update` to sync the locked dependencies in the `poetry.lock` file. This is necessary because Poetry will use the resolved dependencies from the `poetry.lock` file on install if this file is available.

Once the `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` file are in sync run `poetry install --sync` to get the venv in sync with the `poetry.lock` file.

Comment: Is it just easier to always do `poetry install --sync` instead of simply `poetry install`? So that the --sync will always remove deleted packages too?

Comment: Always using `poetry install --sync` is perfectly fine.